# request a js file,not found or does not implement IController

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Exception:Thrown: "The controller for path '/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js' was not found or does not implement IController." (System.Web.HttpException)
A System.Web.HttpException was thrown: "The controller for path '/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js' was not found or does not implement IController."

a js request will find controller ?

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your **resource does not exist or your path is not correct**.

I assume you are creating your custom Controller factory so resource requests will be passed to controller factory when they are not found.